# Как найти корень f(x)->min методом дихотомии?

Tags: c#, winforms

есть функция `f(x)= 2x^4-x+1` нужно найти min методом дихотомии с точность 0.001 и ограничениями `[-1;10]`.

вот набросок кода, который я пытался реализовать. Но суть такова, что он находит не совсем то что нужно.. где `f(a) = 4` , `f(b) = 19991`, `ep = 0,001` , `a и b = [-1;10]`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double a = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    double b = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
    double ep = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
    double fa = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
    double fb = Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
    do
    {
        if (fa > fb)
            a = a + (b - a) / 2;
        else b = a + (b - a) / 2;
    }
    while (Math.Abs((b - a)) / 2 >= ep) ;
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString("f(x)=" + (a-b));
}
```

Comment: А разве не нужно считать `f(a)` и `f(b)` на каждой итерации цикла?

Comment: @CrazyElf, кстати вполне возможно, есть какой то набросок реализации?

Comment: @CrazyElf большое спасибо! У меня получилось реализовать метод!

Comment: Вот и хорошо. На то и задания даются, чтобы вы сами их делали и учились :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо пользователю @CrazyElf

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        double a = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        double b = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
        double ep = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
        do
        {
            if (f(a) > f(b))
                a = a + (b - a) / 2;
            else b = a + (b - a) / 2;
        }
        while (Math.Abs((f(b) - f(a))) / 2 >= ep);
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString("f(x)=" + f(f((b - a)) / 2));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(""+ex.Message, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}

static double f(double x)
{
    return 2*Math.Pow(x, 4) - x + 1;
}
```